# Using the new type() for UUIDGenerator instead of strategy?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, uuid, uuidgenerator

According to the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html), the following usage is deprecated:

```
@GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
```

One shall use the new [`type()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html#type())! But how can I transform my above statement to do the same with the `type()`? Just providing the hibernate UUIDGenerator doesn't work.

Comment: From the doc, `strategy` is a string, `type` is a class. Have you tried `type = org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator.class` ?

Comment: I believe that should be either `@org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator` or `@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", type = org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator.class)`

Comment: @Aserre @Andrey B. Panfilov Nvm, I used: `@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", type = org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator.class)` and got: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator` for all classes using your new approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the two comments above suggest, `type` is now of type class. Thus the fix is simple:

```
@GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            type = org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator.class
    )
```

Comment: Seems good way two replace "strategy" property, but when I user that I get another error concerning dependency injection "Parameter 0 of constructor in org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator' that could not be found".

Comment: @Oscar same. Did you find way to fix it?

Comment: @Denys Bondarenko This has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77128492/uuidgenerator-bean-type-mismatch/77132434#77132434 in case you're curious and still facing the same issue you did earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new annotation **@UuidGenerator**

Old solution:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private UUID id;
```

New solution (since hibernate 6.2):

```
@Id
@UuidGenerator
private UUID id;
```