# UuidGenerator Bean Type Mismatch?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, uuidgenerator

Because [`strategy`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html#strategy()) and [`UUIDGenerator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/UUIDGenerator.html) is deprecated, this is the new UUID Generator:

```
@GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID", 
            type = org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator.class
    )
```

When using this, I get the following error:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator
> required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator' that
> could not be found

I wasn't able to find anything corresponding to this in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/uuid/UuidGenerator.html).

For full disclosure, this is the whole annotation block used:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", type = org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator.class)
@Column(...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really suggest you to use  `@UuidGenerator` instead of

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", type = org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator.class)
```

Something like this:

```
  @Id
  @UuidGenerator
  private UUID id; // or String
```

Because if you are going to check `java docs` of the annotation you will see that `@UuidGenerator` use
`@IdGeneratorType( org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator.class )` that you need.

About the problem i really dont know where can be the problem but the solution that i suggest will help you to do this replacement also  when specifying `@UuidGenerator`, we can choose the concrete version of UUID to generate.

And also some motivation to use it is described into [8.5. User-defined generators](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html)

> These APIs are new in Hibernate 6, and supersede the classic IdentifierGenerator interface and @GenericGenerator annotation from older versions of Hibernate.
>
> @UuidGenerator A more flexible generator for [RFC 4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) UUIDs

Comment: Thanks. More flexible implies you can adjust more with `@UuidGenerator` then with `@GenericGenerator`. May elaborate on this shortly?